# Cannot define aclass property array from brace-encasing initialiser in C++

Tags: c++

This does not compile, I am obliged to set 3 within the [].

Is there a way to let the compiler computes the exact length of the array based on literals?

```
class Foo {
    const uint8_t commands[] = {
        0x90,
        0x91,
        0x92,

    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compiler can deduce and know command's size. you don't need to pass command's size.
from c++11 you can use `constexpr` with `static` to declare const inside a class

```
class Foo {
    constexpr static int commands[] = {
        0x90,
        0x91,
        0x92,
    };
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cnh4o37Pq

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not need one copy per object of that class (thus do not need it to be a real member), yes, make it `static`:

```cpp
class Foo 
{
    static inline const uint8_t commands[] = {0x90, 0x91, 0x92};
};
```

Comment: I upped the answer, though I couldn't do it inline. I had to migrate the code to the cpp file

Answer (score 1):

Following up @Erel answer: I couldn't do an inline so I did the following:

foo.h:

```cpp
class Foo {
    static const uint8_t commands[];
}
```

foo.cpp:

```cpp
const uint8_t Foo::commands[] = {
    0x90,
    0x91,
    0x92,
};

void Foo::bar() {
    Serial.println("sizeof(commands) is ok: %d", sizeof(commands));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking C++ compiler is able to compute the size automatically

```cpp
int main()
{
    const uint8_t commands[] = {
        0x90,
        0x91,
        0x92,

    };
    cout<<"sizeof: "<< sizeof(commands);

    return 0;
}
```

But compiler can't deduce them for class members:

```
class Foo {
     uint8_t commands[];
};
class Foo1 {
     const uint8_t commands[];
};
class Foo2 {
     const uint8_t commands[] = ...;
};
```

As specified in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members): Members of array type cannot deduce their size from member initializers:
[image]
I suppose this is a special constraint for classes, as these are supposed to be shared via header files. And this can be a potential source of inconsistences between headers. Such inconsistences are binary incompatible, can't be detected at compile time, nor linking time. Such binary incompatibility can lead to incorrect, undefined behavior, and crashes, and usualy it leads to that. The cause is very difficult to diagnose. Doing it inside a function never breaks binary incompatibility, as it always gets recompiled and relinked.